# can I create a slider in console c++ and how

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am using `StereoSGBM` to match correspondences to create the disparity map 
can I create a slider on the window to change the parameters of this algorithm? , note that I am using c++ console application. if yes, HOW ?

Comment: You probably can't. May be [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html)  offers an option.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The Console Window is not made for mouse input. You could chop up a little ASCII Art that looks vaguely like a slider and only reacts to keyboard input, but other than that, you need a GUI toolkit.

Comment: actually, that's wrong. Certain operating systems do permit console windows to access the mouse (e. g. Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you refer to the chapter **Interfacing with the mouse** in the **[NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/mouse.html)**.

NCurses is available for many platforms including BSD, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, and Microsoft Windows.

This might be what you need to accomplish your goal.